# How to query character directionality on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, bidi

I am trying to define directionality of text line based on analysis of directionality of characters it includes. 
Each Unicode character has a unique property - directionality defined by Unicode standard. In Java it can be queried via:

```
Character.getDirectionality()
```

Since iOS provides out of the box contextual (aka first strong) text direction I presume that this kind of analysis / processing is done internally by iOS.
    However, I have not found any combination of publically available API in Objective C which would allow me to achieve this.

In NSLocale I found an API (characterDirectionForLanguage) which returns natural text direction for given language (i.e. Arabic / Hebrew -> RTL, English -> LTR). 
    However, I have not found any API which  for a given character would help me to understand to which language does it belong.

We can certainly think about heuristics based on characters ranges. For example define English and Hebrew character ranges and based on inclusion of given 
character in one of them decide on directionality using characterDirectionForLanguage function. However, this is just a heuristic since it does not cover all characters in all languages.

Is there any way to programmatically and reliably identify the directionality of given character in Objective C ?